# Tkinter : Adding image to the window (create_window on the canvas is used)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to add an image in right top of the window. This is the image I want to put up there : https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6BkR.jpg

I tried this :

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\sel\Desktop\logo.png")

tk.label = Label(canvas, image=photo)

canvas.create_window(125,10, window=photo, anchor=tk.NW)
```

But it didn t work.I got this error.

File "", line 22

photo = PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\sel\Desktop\logo.png")
                           ^

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
window.configure()

ws = window.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = window.winfo_screenheight()
w = 800  # width for the Tk root
h = 600  # height for the Tk root
x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)

window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg="white", width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()
canvas_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(canvas, command=canvas.yview)
canvas_scroll.place(relx=1, rely=0, relheight=1, anchor=tk.NE)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=canvas_scroll.set, scrollregion=())


#photo = PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\sel\Desktop\logo.png")
#tk.label = Label(canvas, image=photo)
#canvas.create_window(125,10, window=photo, anchor=tk.NW)


l0 = tk.Label(canvas, text="강재 NESTING 최적화 프로그램", font= "calibri 32",fg="royalblue4",bg="white" )
canvas.create_window(125,70, window=l0, anchor=tk.NW)


l1 = tk.Label(canvas, text="MIN")
canvas.create_window(125,150, window=l1, anchor=tk.NW)


l2 = tk.Label(canvas, text="MAX")
canvas.create_window(260,150, window=l2, anchor=tk.NW)


l3 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Sheet 폭(SW)")
canvas.create_window(3,170, window=l3, anchor=tk.NW)

minw_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_minw_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=minw_var)
canvas.create_window(190,180, window=entry_minw_number)

maxw_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_maxw_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=maxw_var)
canvas.create_window(325,180, window=entry_maxw_number)

l4 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Sheet 높이(SH)")
canvas.create_window(3,190, window=l4, anchor=tk.NW)

minl_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_minl_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=minl_var)
canvas.create_window(190,200, window=entry_minl_number)

maxl_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_maxl_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=maxl_var)
canvas.create_window(325,200, window=entry_maxl_number)

l5 = tk.Label(canvas, text="소요 Component 개수")
canvas.create_window(3,210, window=l5, anchor=tk.NW)

rect_var = tk.IntVar()
entry_rect_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=rect_var)
canvas.create_window(260,220, window=entry_rect_number)

l6 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Area")
canvas.create_window(3,230, window=l6, anchor=tk.NW)

area_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_area_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=area_var)
canvas.create_window(260,240, window=entry_area_number)


window.title("Rectangle Configuration")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Did it display the wrong image? The right image in the wrong place? Did it thrown an error, and if so, what error?

Comment: `create_window` is used to put tkinter's widget on canvas. `PhotoImage` is not widget. `Label` (with `PhotoImage` inside) is widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley I edited the problem above. Please, take a look

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you supply the `create_window` function with the image instead of the label containing the image. Try using `create_image` instead:

```
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\sel\Desktop\logo.png")
canvas.create_image(125,10, image=photo, anchor=tk.NW)
```

Comment: There is an error.
  File "<ipython-input-8-2a6c1cc141fa>", line 26
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\sel\Desktop\logo.png")
                              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: You'll have to specify that the string should use literal backslashes and not interpret them by putting a "r" before the string. I updated my example.

Answer (score 1):

`create_window` is used to put tkinter's widget on canvas.

`PhotoImage` is not widget. But `Label` (with `PhotoImage` inside) is a widget.

So use `window=label` instead of `window=photo`

```
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\sel\Desktop\logo.png")
label = tk.Label(canvas, image=photo)
canvas.create_window(125,10, window=label, anchor=tk.NW)
```

But you would rather use `create_image` as in @figbeam's answer.

Comment: I got this error. SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: It can be problem with `\U` in `"C:\Users\sel\Desktop\logo.png"` - which is used to put code of unicode in text - use \\ or `/` in path "C:\\Users\\sel\\Desktop\\logo.png" or "C:/Users/sel/Desktop/logo.png"

Comment: The image has a ring around it. The picture and the background of the window matches but there is a separation. How do we remove that?

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page. You will have place to put screenshot with your problem